# Is transaction history available as a part of the blockchain implementation, or do I have to implement saving token history myself

Tags: solidity, transactions, blockchain, etherscan, storage

I am implementing a CryptoKitties style of ERC721 tokens, to be deployed on Ethereum. But I am not clear how to implement the transaction history of the individual token?

For example all the different ERC-721 tokens(artworks) will have different prices depending on their demand, and similarly they will have their own trading history, having sold at different prices and buyers. It makes sense to show this provenance, how it was sold when it was sold etc, as it related to the value creation of the artwork tied to the ERC721 token.

Do I have to implement this functionality myself, or is it a integral part of blockchain. If blockchain is a public ledger, then where/how can I get the transaction history of each token to simplete get the historical sale price and dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethereum blockchain persists all past state transitions i.e. tranactions.

You can read it back over various Web3.js or Web3.py APIs, like `web3.eth.getBlock()` and `web3.eth.Contract().allEvents()`.